# Push notification for cross-platform app

Tags: node.js, push-notification, cross-platform

I want to allow users to set the time and date they want to receive a push notification to remind them about a task they need to complete. I am using node.js for the back-end and PostgreSQL for the database. Is there ways of accomplishing this and if so examples would be appreciated

Comment: What client technology?

Comment: JavaScript, HTML and CSS

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32571280/2579220